# Including documentation in xml using xsd schemas

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xsd schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/PurchaseOrderSchema.xsd"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/PurchaseOrderSchema.xsd"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xsd:element name="PurchaseOrder" type="tns:PurchaseOrderType"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
         <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                purchasing products
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="ShipTo" type="tns:USAddress" maxOccurs="2"/>
   <xsd:element name="BillTo" type="tns:USAddress"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="OrderDate" type="xsd:date"/>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="name"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="city"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="state"  type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="zip"    type="xsd:integer"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" fixed="US"/>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

And the following corresponding xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PurchaseOrder OrderDate="2012-12-13">
  <ShipTo country="US">
    <name>sam</name>
    <street>paul</street>
    <city>ny</city>
    <state>ny</state>
    <zip>1234</zip>
  </ShipTo>
  <BillTo country="US">
    <name>sarah</name>
    <street>missa</street>
    <city>ny</city>
    <state>ny</state>
    <zip>125</zip>
  </BillTo>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

I currently have the xml and the xsd files. Note that the xml file doesn't have any documentations.

I would like to find a way in python to include the comments in the xml file. Above each corresponding element.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the comments"? What comments are you talking about? Do you want to add `<!-- some comment -->` comments?

Comment: @Progman YES...

Comment: I want to add them according to the name of the element so not exactly..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you want to do. Then add your attempts on how to solve your problem and the problems/errors you get from your attempts.